Problem with Angular Schematics in IntelliJ IDEA Connected to WSL2
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA connected to WSL2 for my Angular development. When I attempt to use Angular Schematics via the "Right-click -> New -> Angular Schematics" option, I can see the list of available schematics. However, regardless of which schematic I select, IntelliJ always defaults to generating an app-shell.
Has anyone encountered this issue and managed to get Angular Schematics working correctly in IntelliJ IDEA with WSL2? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.


